# Iframe structured site

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, web, structure

I've been wondering quite a while, whether or not to create my site in an iframe structured environment. 
What I mean by this, is a site with a static menu on the left hand site along with a static menu on the top.

Visual description:

[image]

Does this setup limit capabilities of the site or does it improve it?
Will I be able to entail all elements as a site structured page would.

All in all I'm asking whether it's smarter to create a 80+ site webpage within an iframe structured environment, with two main menu's or whether it's smarter to just link 80+ different sites with the same setup.

Comment: I don't see any sane reason why you'd want to do this. Can you elaborate on your use-case?

Comment: How many websites do you see where iframes are used to maintain a menu across pages? Very few. That should be a hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use iframes for structure. Iframes don't go well with multiple screen sizes, mobile browsers etc. They also introduce unneeded complexity to scripts and will generate a lot more HTTP requests that monolithic pages.
Modern web frameworks allow you to create templates for navigation menu, headers, footers and whatever else you will need, and use them uniformly throughout all of your pages.

For a simple example, in Django: http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/templates.html

Answer (score 0):

Using iframes to format your site will definitely limit the user experience.  Have you ever tried to view a site that uses iframes for layout on using a mobile device?

CSS was created for layout, there are CSS based alternatives that will allow you to place your side elements and top elements staticly

Comment: Was planning on creating a whole other site for mobile devices though. But I get the feeling, that whether or not, I should not build it around an iframe?

Answer (score 0):

This structure was popular years ago with the [`<frameset>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frameset.asp) attribute, which is now officially deprecated in HTML5 because it does not support responsive designs and adds unwanted complexity to your site.

I would suggest using AJAX to dynamically change single parts of your site.